# A suitable guide for migrating log4j.properties files from Log4j version 1 to 2

Tags: migration, log4j, log4j2, configuration-files, properties-file

I am currently working on a large project that uses log4j version 1 exclusively (as it was developed a long time ago) and we've recently looked into migrating to log4j version 2. While I have already replaced much of the code references and added the dependencies, the project uses a couple dozen custom configuration files in the form of log4j.properties files.

I am just wondering if there is a guide which details how to convert between the log4j.properties and log4j2.properties, as it seems as though the properties file format is still in use. Since the project covers a wide variety of properties is there a blanket converter manual as we would like to avoid trying to convert to an xml format as none of us have used it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no guide that tells you how to convert between Log4j 1 properties and Log4j 2 properties. That would actually be fairly complex because it would have to accomplish 2 things:

1. Describe the syntax of Log4j 2 properties and how that differs from Log4j 1 properties.
2. Describe the differences in configuration between the various elements such as the ConsoleAppender, RollingFileAppender, etc.

The Log4j [configuration guide](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties) does provide an overview of the properties syntax although it could use some more detailed explanation.

To be honest, I resisted implementing configuration with properties since configuration works very differently in Log4j 2. No matter what configuration syntax is used the configuration is converted into a hierarchy of Node definitions that each contain key/value attributes. By their nature properties files are not hierarchical. To emulate that you have to create property names where the elements are represented in the dot notation. For example, appender.console means this is the configuration for the console appender and all the fields that start with that are the attributes or sub-nodes. This gets quite cumbersome (IMO) when defining something like the RollingFileAppender. In properties you have:

```
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = target/rolling2/test1-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 2
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=100MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5
```

vs the corresponding XML

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${filename}" filePattern="target/rolling2/test1-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz">
  <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n"/>
  <Policies>
    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="2" modulate="true" />
    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100MB" />
  </Policies>
  <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5"/>
</RollingFile>
```

Likewise, YAML and JSON are hierarchical in nature so are also good choices for the configuration. In JSON this would be:

```
"RollingFile": {
  "name": "RollingFile,
  "fileName": "${filename}",
  "filePattern": "target/rolling2/test1-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz",
  "PatternLayout": {
    "Pattern": "%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n"
  },
  "Policies": {
    "TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy": {
      "interval": 2,
      "modulate": true,
    },
    "SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy": {
      "size": "100MB"
    }
  }
}
```

But you will notice that even here XML can take up less space than JSON. This is primarily because in XML attributes can either be expressed as as attributes on the element or as child elements. If child elements were used in the XML example it would be essentially the same size as the JSON example.

That said, if you compare the properties syntax shown here to the corresponding XML or JSON it should provide guidance on what you have to do for other elements.